# Alternative of show partitions of Hive in BigQuery

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have a requirement where I have a partitioned table in BigQuery(Hourly partition) and I have to write a batch job which will process one partition at a time.

In hive, its pretty easy to do that like I can do show partition in the main table and one metadata table where i can maintain the processed partition and later create a difference between the two dataset using except to identify the remaining partition to process.

I'm looking this in BigQuery where I can do something similar to show partition on main table and maintain a metadata table where I can maintain the processed partition.

I found something like I can do that on main table

SELECT DISTINCT FORMAT_DATETIME('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', EXTRACT(DATETIME FROM _PARTITIONTIME)) FROM DATASET.TABLE_NAME

But this will scan the full table and overhead on the cost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using legacy sql you can run the following:

```
#legacySQL
SELECT 
partition_id
FROM [project_id:dataset.table$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]
```

see additional documentation here on the [partition summary table](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-column-partitions#listing_partitions_in_a_partitioned_table)

Comment: Is there any other way to get the partition information? Also to execute this, we would need to use QueryJobConfiguration. Any other way we can execute this query and get the partition information like we can get in hive.

Comment: the `#legacySQL` will allow you to not have to update the QueryJobConfiguration

```bq query \
 '#legacySQL
 SELECT
 partition_id
 FROM [bigquery-public-data:wikipedia.pageviews_2015$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__]'```

Comment: Basically, I want to execute this via Java Code. Hence checking if there is any other way apart from QueryJobConfiguration.